# Penetration Testing List

Tags: penetration-test

I have been to various documents such as OSSTMM, NIST 800-115, PCI DSS pentesting document. But is there any place where I can find out baseline list for internal network penetration testing? For example, a list which has a common application list which I should be checking for penetration testing in Windows, Linux, Network devices etc.

Comment: I think that's what the whole "enumeration phase" is for ...

Comment: You can have a look to [owasp lists](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Appendix_A:_Testing_Tools).

Comment: @Trevor65  I asked for network penetration, not web application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for inspiration for what to test for to make sure that your enumeration phase isn't missing something obvious, then I would look to the automated scanning tools as your baseline.

- nmap scripts
- metasploit scanning modules
- OpenVAS/Nessus
- etc.

If you miss something that is in those lists, then you certainly have a gap in your enumeration processes. But then you should be using those tools as part of your enumeration phase anyway.

Comment: In addition I'd say you're going to want to enumerate Active Directory (if applicable). If you're not concerned about PowerShell logging in your environment then [PowerSploit](https://github.com/PowerShellMafia/PowerSploit) can be incredibly beneficial.

Comment: I am aware about the tools used for enumeration process. But I cannot possibly wait for the vulnerabilities to come up from these tools and then search the exploits. If I am aware about the common vulnerabilities specific to OS, then I can atleast have some of my homework ready before I start the penetration process.

Comment: @tech_enthusiast but that does not appear to be what you asked for. I'm not saying to use the tools to search for the newest vulnerabilities, I'm saying to use the *scanners* in those tools as a baseline to know what to look at. A common application/services/location/port/etc. list.

Comment: @schroeder I understand your point to check the scanner. But is there any general list containing which ports/services/applications etc. to check which I can use to prepare the baseline ?

Comment: @tech_enthusiast If I knew of any, I would mention them. The problem with any published lists is that they might get stale, so I'm not sure that anyone would create them.

Answer (score 4):

Its in general up to the pentester, the context, and your abilities...you can check those links for hints:

1. [Network Penetration Testing Checklist](https://gbhackers.com/network-penetration-testing-checklist-examples/)
2. [Web Application Penetration Testing Checklist](https://gbhackers.com/web-application-penetration-testing-checklist-a-detailed-cheat-sheet/)
3. [Pentest methodology](http://www.isaca.org/chapters3/Atlanta/AboutOurChapter/Documents/Penetration%20Testing.pdf)